# How to shift yaxis ( or axis ) tick labels at a required position in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

Consider this matrix (matG) for which I am trying to make a heatmap

```
48  12  6   13
12  48  12  36
6   12  54  14
13  36  14  84
```

Since it is a symmetric matrix so I need only triangular heatmap, masking the upper triangle data of the matrix.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.xticks(fontsize=12,weight='bold')
**plt.yticks(fontsize=12,weight='bold',ha='right') #trying to shift the ticklabel text**


mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(matG.T, dtype=bool))
cmap = sns.color_palette('OrRd')

labl2 = ['Class1','Class2','Class3','Class4']

ax = sns.heatmap(matG,mask=mask,cmap=cmap,center=0,cbar=False,square=True, linewidths=.5,
            cbar_kws={"shrink": .5},xticklabels=labl2,yticklabels=labl2,annot=True,fmt='g')

ax.get_xticklabels()[3].set_visible(False); ax.get_yticklabels()[0].set_visible(False)

ax.xaxis.get_majorticklines()[3].set_visible(False); ax.yaxis.get_majorticklines()[0].set_visible(False)

**for tick in ax.get_yticklabels():
    x,y = tick.get_position()
    tick.set_position((x,y+44))**
    
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.35,-0.1)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
```

This gives me the following plot: [image]

But the problem is, as you can see in the picture, the y-axis tick labels are not in the center. I have shown by an arrow that the text needs to be shifted upwards.
In the code, I have made the relevant syntax above bold using which I tried to bring the tick labels to the center of the tick and make it look symmetric. But it is not happening. Any suggestions, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used 'ha', instead use 'va':
`plt.yticks(fontsize=12,weight='bold',va='center')`

Answer (score 2):

You can center y-tick labels vertically with:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(['Class2','Class3','Class4'], va='center')
```

OR

```
ax.set_yticklabels(labl2[1:], va='center')
```